# Colonial style casing / backband and alternatives

Tags: trim

Here's my issue, I have windows and door casing that appears to be 1x6 that was custom routed,  my down stairs is almost identical but has a backband.  My current baseboard trim I've come to find has been screwed in by the previous owner and I can't remove it easily to cut it to accommodate backband.

[image: currently installed trim]

Since the trim is cut nearly identically, this below picture is the style I'm going for
[image]
[image]

Ideally I don't want to add anymore width, so I was thinking of adding some shoetrim or stop trim around the outside edge to get the same look.  I feel like it's wrong to do this, so before i start nailing away with some shoe trim i want to hear some ideas.  The only concern i can think of would be the look of the trim from a side profile. Who knows, maybe I'm being a little OCD.

Comment: Maybe I'm not looking at it right but I don't see anything wrong with your plan. As long as you don't exceed the width of the sill it seems fine to me. Looks like you have some nice woodwork in your home, kudos!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment!  Back band would wrap around the outside and add dimension, width and a seamless side profile.  If I add stop from the side there would be a seam visible from the current white trim to the taller stop.  Maybe I'll mock it up and take a picture in an hour or so.

Comment: Screwed in trim can't be easily removed? I thought that was the beauty of screws, they back right out with little to no damage! If there's filler over them, I'd think that would chip out reasonably easily with a bit of banging & prying...

Comment: The filler appears to be stronger then the wood. :).  I wish that was the case.  I can't even pry far enough to get a multi tool in there to cut them.   If I start pulling harder either the wall behind it (plaster) begins to crack or the wood starts breaking. :(

Comment: @Graphus thanks for the advice!  Everything is coming together nicely.

Comment: FWIW I think the door & baseboard trim style is lovely and worth the effort to match :)